# Hyperlink a Record in lightning:datatable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, lightning-datatable

[image]

Am trying to accomplish a POC in my project. We have a lightning Datatable using . I could generate a set of records to display on the component. But I need one column to be hyperlinked to navigate to the corresponding record when I click on them. The data table fields and object is passed dynamically at runtime either from Community Page/App Builder page/ Some Lightning container components.

**Problem:**

I couldn't figure out a way to make the first column as hyperlinked. I tried to work around by creating a formula field with HYPERLINK("/" &Id, "View Record"). But it generates this(Ref My Screenshot) on the data table in UI. If anyone can help with some workaround?

**Component:**

```
<aura:component controller="lightningTableController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="title" type="string" default="My Interations" />
<aura:attribute name="recLimit" type="String" default="10" /> 
<aura:attribute name="object" type="string" default="Case" />
<aura:attribute name="fields" type="String" default="RecIdURL__c,FSA_BTO_Date_Of_Service__c,Subject,Type,FSA_BTO_Service_Requested__c" />   
<aura:attribute name="sortedBy" type="string" default="FSA_BTO_Date_Of_Service__c" />
<aura:attribute name="sortedDirection" type="string" default="DESC" />
<aura:attribute name="mydata" type="object" />
<aura:attribute name="mycolumn" type="object" />

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />

<lightning:card title="{!v.title}" >

    <lightning:datatable data="{!v.mydata}" columns="{!v.mycolumn}" 
                         onsort="{!c.updateColumnSorting}" sortedBy="{!v.sortedBy}" 
                         sortedDirection="{!v.sortedDirection}" 
                         hideCheckboxColumn="true" 
                         onrowselection="{!c.getSelectedName}" keyField="Id" />
</lightning:card>
```

**Controller.JS:**

```
({
init : function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.getLightningTableData(component);
},
updateColumnSorting: function (cmp, event, helper) {
    var fieldName = event.getParam('fieldName');
    var sortDirection = event.getParam('sortDirection');
    cmp.set("v.sortedBy", fieldName);
    cmp.set("v.sortedDirection", sortDirection);
    helper.sortData(cmp, fieldName, sortDirection);
},
getSelectedName: function (component, event) {

    var selectedRows = event.getParam('selectedRows');
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++){
       console.log('>>>',selectedRows[i].Subject);
    }

  }
})
```

**Helper.JS**

```
({
getLightningTableData : function(component) {
    var recLimit = component.get("v.recLimit");
    var sColumn = component.get("v.fields");
    var sObject = component.get("v.object");
    var action = component.get("c.getsObjectRecords");
    action.setParams({
        ObjectName : sObject,
        fieldstoget : sColumn,
        recLimit : recLimit
    });
    action.setCallback(this,function(response){
    var state = response.getState();
    if(state == 'SUCCESS'){
        var rtnValue = response.getReturnValue();
        component.set("v.mycolumn",rtnValue.tableColumn);
        component.set("v.mydata",rtnValue.tableRecord);
    }
   });
     $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
sortData: function (cmp, fieldName, sortDirection) {
    var data = cmp.get("v.mydata");
    var reverse = sortDirection !== 'asc';
    data.sort(this.sortBy(fieldName, reverse))
    cmp.set("v.mydata", data);
},
sortBy: function (field, reverse, primer) {
    var key = primer ?
        function(x) {return primer(x[field])} :
        function(x) {return x[field]};
    reverse = !reverse ? 1 : -1;
    return function (a, b) {
        return a = key(a), b = key(b), reverse * ((a > b) - (b > a));
    }
  }
})
```

**Design:**

```
<design:component >
<design:attribute name="title" label="Header Title" description="Title for the data table" />
<design:attribute name="object" label="Object API Name" description="API Name of the Object" />
<design:attribute name="fields" label="Fields API Name" />
<design:attribute name="recLimit" label="Number of Records to Display" description="Limit value for SOQL"/>
```

**APEX:**

```
public with sharing class lightningTableController {

@AuraEnabled public static lightningTableWraper getsObjectRecords(String ObjectName,String fieldstoget,Integer recLimit){     

    List<String> lstfieldstoget = fieldstoget.split(',');
    List<lightningTableColumnWrapper> lstTableColumn = new list<lightningTableColumnWrapper> ();

    DescribeSObjectResult objResult = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(ObjectName).getDescribe();

    for(String field : lstfieldstoget){
       lightningTableColumnWrapper colWrapper = new lightningTableColumnWrapper();
       DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = objResult.fields.getMap().get(field).getDescribe();
       colWrapper.label = fieldResult.getLabel();
       colWrapper.fieldName = fieldResult.getName();
       colWrapper.type = String.valueof(fieldResult.getType()).toLowerCase();
       colWrapper.sortable = true;
       lstTableColumn.add(colWrapper);
    }
    Id loggedUser = UserInfo.getUserId();
    String queryString = 'Select '+ String.escapeSingleQuotes(String.join(lstfieldstoget,','))+
                         ' from '+ String.escapeSingleQuotes(ObjectName) + ' Limit ' +recLimit;

    LightningTableWraper ltngTableWrapper = new LightningTableWraper();
    ltngTableWrapper.tableRecord = database.query(queryString);
    ltngTableWrapper.tableColumn = lstTableColumn;

    return ltngTableWrapper;

}


 public class lightningTableColumnWrapper {
    @AuraEnabled
    public string label {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String fieldName {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public string type {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public boolean sortable {get;set;}

}

public class lightningTableWraper{
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<sObject> tableRecord {get;Set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<lightningTableColumnWrapper> tableColumn {get;set;}

  }
}
```

Comment: Share the current UI as well.

Comment: Commenting to follow. Could be useful to me too.

Comment: Added my screenshot. @itzmukeshy7

Comment: Here you can take help of the `type: 'url'` and `typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'linkLabel' }}` to show some useful link label of the column;

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 This is the answer I would have given. Perhaps you might want to fill in some extra details and make it official?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can take help of the `type: url` and `typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'linkLabel' }}` to show some useful link label of the column;

**Working with Column Data**

Here we have two options

1. `type` possible values are(action, ..., **url**);
2. `typeAttributes` value depends on the `type` option value like for **url** we have **(label, target)**;

Here is the example of the same: [lightning:datatable](https://itzruns-developer-edition.ap5.force.com/s/lightning-datatable)

Below is the example of the options:

[image: Type and type attributes usage]

And we can also do this type adjustment just before assigning the columns settings to the attribute in the helper(if not want to do in the Apex):

```
({
  getLightningTableData: function (component) {
    var recLimit = component.get('v.recLimit');
    var sColumn = component.get('v.fields');
    var sObject = component.get('v.object');
    var action = component.get('c.getsObjectRecords');
    action.setParams({
      ObjectName: sObject,
      fieldstoget: sColumn,
      recLimit: recLimit
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function (response) {
      var state = response.getState();
      if (state === 'SUCCESS') {
        var rtnValue = response.getReturnValue();

        rtnValue.tableColumn.forEach(function (column) {
          switch (column.fieldName) {
            case 'Show_Record__c':
              column.type = 'url';
              column['typeAttributes'] = { label: { fieldName: 'Name' } };
              break;

            default:
              break;
          }
        });

        component.set('v.mycolumn', rtnValue.tableColumn);
        component.set('v.mydata', rtnValue.tableRecord);
      }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  },
  /* more methods */
})
```

Comment: Thanks so much @itzmukeshy7 That worked like a charm. Except that i changed my formula of the field to => "/"&id.

Comment: Yes that I missed to mention here. :)

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 how did you hid the Name column?

Comment: @sebascanseco I didn't hide any column, can you please explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 never mind. I missed the Account Name it's been shown in your example. This is a great explanation, but I was wondering if there's a way to hide the Account Name column as it's redundant with the first column.

Answer (score 2):

Similar answer here:

```
component.set('v.columns', [
        {label: 'Header Name', fieldName: 'Link', type: 'url',
        typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'Name' }, target: '_blank'}},
        ]);
```

Source: http://www.infallibletechie.com/2018/07/how-to-hyperlink-record-in.html

Comment: please elaborate on your answer, otherwise, it might be considered a code dump, which is of no rea value on this forum. While you are ate it, please take a moment to read [ask], thanks

Comment: This is a good answer because it shows the exact JSON required to add `typeAttributes` to the column definition, which seems to be missing from the Salesforce data table docs.