# Record URL in lightning:datatable in Community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community

I am trying to create case table in Community with first column which will show Case Number and will be link to record page.

I created formula field Show_Case__c [formula: "/"&id].
Also I reference it :

```
 {label: 'Case Number', fieldName: 'Show_Case__c', type: 'url',sortable: true,typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'CaseNumber'}}}
```

**Component**

```
<aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>
<aura:attribute name="data" type="Object"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

<aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.columns))}">
    <lightning:datatable aura:id="myTable" columns="{!v.columns}" data="{!v.data}" keyField="Id"  hideCheckboxColumn="false"  />
</aura:if>
```

**Apex**

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Case> getCases1(){
    List<Case> cases = [SELECT  Show_Case__c, Id, CaseNumber FROM Case];
    return cases;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
tableset : function(component,event,helper) {

        var queryaction = component.get("c.getCases1");
         queryaction.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {

                component.set('v.data',response.getReturnValue());

                var columns = [{label: 'Show_Case__c', fieldName: 'CaseNumber', type: 'url',sortable: true,filterable: true,typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'CaseNumber'}}}];
                component.set('v.columns',columns);
            }


        });
        $A.enqueueAction(queryaction); 
    },
```

The error which I receive is Cannot read property 'type' of undefined.

I used [Hyperlink a Record in lightning:datatable](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/212859/hyperlink-a-record-in-lightningdatatable) for reference.

How to get this work?

I will appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide few extra details like code snippet? Is it exact replica of code you mentioned above? When do you receive this error  on load or click of link? Does it provide you with stack trace?

Comment: I receive the error on load. I can see from console.log  the fields are passed with correct values as shown in the reference link. If I change the places It is showing the id, but not the number as well as it is not working on click of the link. (of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to show case number in community as link to record detail!

1. Create Custom formula field.

Formula:

```
LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_260, FIND( '/services', $Api.Partner_Server_URL_260)) 
+ 's/detail/' + Id]
```

2. Put  the field in Apex SOQL query
3. Then this code will be working

{ 
  label: 'Case Number', fieldName: 'Show_Case__c', type: 'url',
  sortable: 
 true,typeAttributes: {label:{ fieldName: 'CaseNumber'}}
 }

Answer (score 0):

I hope the issue is somewhere else. I tried the same code and it is working for me. Another thing I noticed, you don't have to explicitly parse the JSON (`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()))`).

You can set the response directly `cmp.set('v.mydata', response.getReturnValue());` in the datatable.

Component Markup

```
<aura:component controller="lightningTableController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="title" type="string" default="My Cases" />
    <aura:attribute name="mydata" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="mycolumns" type="List"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>    
    <lightning:card title="{!v.title}">
        <lightning:datatable data="{!v.mydata}" 
                             columns="{!v.mycolumns}" 
                             keyField="Id"
                             hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

Component Controller

```
({
    init: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        var action = cmp.get('c.getCases');
        action.setCallback(this, function (response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                cmp.set('v.mydata', response.getReturnValue());
                cmp.set('v.mycolumns', [
                    {label: 'Case Number', fieldName: 'Show_Case__c', type: 'url',sortable: true,typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'CaseNumber'}}},
                    {label: 'Subject', fieldName: 'Subject', type: 'text'},
                    {label: 'Status', fieldName: 'Status', type: 'text'}
                ]);                
            } else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                console.error(errors);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Apex

```
public class lightningTableController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Case> getCases() {
        List<Case> cases = [SELECT Id, CaseNumber,  Subject, Status, Show_Case__c FROM Case];
        //Add isAccessible() check
        return cases;
    }
}
```

Screen Capture

[image]

Comment: For me is working in lightning but not in community