# Hyperlinking a Record in Lightning:datatable

Tags: url, lightning-datatable, hyperlink

Having an issue with just one small part of [this answer someone gave on how to Hyperlink to records in Lightning Data Table](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/212859/hyperlink-a-record-in-lightningdatatable)

my question is what is the second ID (the one with key value of "Id" in the picture) in the object that is being passed to V.data? the "show_record_c" appears to be the standard 15 digit record ID used in hyperlinks so im not sure what that 18 digit id might be / if it is needed.

[image: picture from Stack overflow question]

The object being passed to v.data is a URL (specifically Hyperlink to a record) linking to a record. I know i can create an object with record ID and a Name, just don't want to get too far down the road and discover that the 18 digit id is something essential

Comment: They're both Salesforce Ids. See the linked question for more information (maybe more than you want to know!) about the format of 15-character and 18-character Salesforce Ids, which can be used interchangeably in all Salesforce APIs and URLs.

Comment: so the 18 digit is just a converted 15 digit (just confirming before i mark it as "that solved my problem")

Comment: It's really the same Id. The final three characters are there to disambiguate for tools like Excel that don't do case-respecting comparisons. See the linked Q for more.

Comment: yep i did read it, and it seemed like that was the case but wanted to doublecheck. Or maybe better question, is the 18 digit id needed in this situation?